# I'm getting this nullReference exception in ASP MVC when loading a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**getting error of object reference null when i am trying to redirect from my controller to view**
@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "MainPage";**//here i am getting error of object reference null**
```

}

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_jk52xg0t
  StackTrace:
       at ASP._Page_Views_sok_sok_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\cbca3c55\39d693c4\App_Web_jk52xg0t.0.cs:line 0
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: no view bag is not null i have checked thrice

Comment: @jprofitt ViewBag is dynamic

Comment: Do you mind post your complete code in this cshtml? As it doesn't mean that the exception really caused by ViewBag event you saw the exception thrown from ViewBag in debugger.

Comment: what i am doing is that i am storing my value in tempadata from testpage and using on main page controller

Comment: ok posting my code please wait

Comment: i am trying to post the code but stack overflow keep giving me errors your post consist of code only....really pissed offf from this error

Comment: check if passed model is null or not

Answer (score 0):

Check what `model` your view is binded to.

In view

```
@model YourModel
```

Make sure that you are passing this model from controller to view

In controller

```
var model=new YourModel();
 return View(model);
```